# What caused these symbols in a text screen scrape?

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-scraping, screen-scraping

so here is the image first off

[image]

So in the image, behind the red blot is some personal info that I am masking. It just says some alphanumeric characters.

What is happening is I am reading from this website 
http://www.origoservices.com/

The technology I am using is .NET 2.0 based. What I am doing is reading from a non-interactive field that contains 7/8 character length profile number that I wish to read from the screen. 99/100 times it works fine, no extra text padding or strange symbols but in the last 6 months this has happened 3 times and I'm not sure why. Can someone point me in the right direction where these symbols come from? I can't seem to find them in any UTF symbol pack or unicode symbol pack. I tried removing all alpha numeric characters from this string with a regex pattern and then performing an infinite loop where I would check the string for containing CharAt(Loop Iteration Value) and incrementally checking it but that didn't prove fruitful. This was a HEX based search (I believe) e.g. CharAt(62) = '>'.

I've been trawling through every symbol site I can find to see where the symbol may have come from, like an unknown data set but no joy there either. Now I'm looking at the code where I scrape out the value from the screen and I don't see anything off there that would cause this.

My assumption following all this is that, somewhere on the client side they are putting data in via some method that is putting some unknown symbols/padding in the text field that the browser isn't rendering and when I scrape it down my .NET interpreter is showing symbols for these padding cases, though i'm not sure as I have no way to identify them. I can visibly see these values when I open my text/string item but I can't identify what set of symbols they belong to.

Things I've googled
strange arrow symbols
Symbols with two horizontal arrows facing each other
unknown symbol looks like 'H'
weird character looks like 'H'/ arrows pointing at each other

and about 30 other variations but I keep getting the same data set results to look up.

Does anybody recognize these symbols or know what might have caused them to be padded in to a non-interactive text field? The only thing I can decipher from the symbols is there is a set of 4 symbols that recur 4 times. Not sure what I can draw from that though.

Any help much appreciated, even point me towards a data set that contains these and I can work from there would be amazing help!

Thanks

Comment: These look like [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) box-drawing characters.  No idea where they might be coming from, though, without more detail of what you're pulling and how.

Comment: How are you screen scraping; reading text contents in a specific `div`, OCR on specific screen coords, etc?

Comment: One other thought - UTF-8 data for non-Latin scripts has a lot of characters >0x80, where the box-drawing characters live.  It might be UTF-8 that is not being properly decoded.  Are you scraping English text or text in another language?

Comment: so the software I use is built on top of a .NET code base, I use a high level 'graph-like' way of programming. I'll give all the info I have though, it's a HTML element, the ClassName is ReadOnly, it's tag name is 'SPAN', it has an XPATH '/HTML/BODY(1)/DIV(1)/DIV(2)/DIV(2)/FORM(1)/FIELDSET(1)/DIV(4)/DIV(2)/SPAN(1)', it also has an ID "ctl00_ctl00_MiddleContent_MainContent_ctrlTransferSummary_ltbReceivingContractReference". that's the unique stuff. the method of reading from the screen takes an element ID'd by these attributes, Get Current Value action, Data Type Text and a variable to store it

Comment: Comment was a bit long but I hope this information helps clarify how this programming tool operates. if I can crack into the base code I will update with exactly what I find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have posted an answer sooner apologies.

Turns out the software I was using to read from the script was fine, the error in the text symbols appearing on screen originated from the client during a migration process where they were collating data on their systems in an effort to move forward onto another platform. As it happens one of the machines they were using to upload data from was a DOS box type machine that had some files from when the company was younger. Somehow the files when they were being crossed into the main network of the company had kept their box-draw characters in the name and were uploaded to the site by script.

I only managed to figure this out by seeing a file being uploaded with these characters and then ringing the company to find out what it was and someone mentioned the DOS machine and tested it and the behavior replicated. Gonna tag this answer with some key words hopefully other people don't get plagued by this problem in the future. Thank you to @cxw for pointing me in the right direction from the get go.

unknown symbols, box drawing characters, weird arrow characters, unknown charset on screen